# Stochastic domination and coupling of point processes with random intensity

Tags: stochastic-processes

Suppose we have two (regular) point processes $N, N^*$ on the half real line (but more general spaces welcome). I will characterize these by their conditional intensity function (which uniquely determines them---see Prop. 7.2.IV p.233 Daley & Vere-Jones, An intro to the theory of point processes. Vol. I). I interpret "regular" to mean that they don't explode and have finitely-many points on any finite interval, almost surely.

The conditional intensity function is $\lambda(t)$ which is the instantaneous intensity at time $t$ conditioned on the history of the process up to that time. In other words, assume we know the point locations before time $t$, and just need to "simulate" the process forward in time from there.

Assume that we have $\lambda(t)\leq\lambda^*(t)$ for the conditional intensities of these two point processes, and for any $t$, when the realized histories are ordered with $N^*$ having a point wherever $N$ does. Since $\lambda(0)\leq\lambda^*(0)$, I feel we can increment the processes forward in time a tad and $N^*$ should have a point first, and if $N$ has a point, then $N^*$ should also have a point. Of course, with each step forward, we are then including some history and changing the conditional intensity function.

I can imagine creating a discretization of these point processes and constructing a domination there (which I understand better), and then using standard weak convergence theory, but I'm hoping to avoid that to make the argument shorter and cleaner.

My question is: can couple these process so that wherever $N$ has a point, then $N^*$ also has a point. And then we can continue doing this for all time, since their conditional intensities are always ordered, as long as the realized history has that desired domination?

How do I formalize this? What I am stuck on, is that I sort of understand that the counting processes associated with these should be ordered, but I can't quite grasp it at the point process level (that is, without resorting to a discretization and using weak convergence).

As an example, consider two cox point processes driven by a Markov process. Let $\lambda(t)$ be a continuous time Markov process that jumps between two values $1,2$ and let $\lambda^*(t)$ have the same generator matrix but jumps between values $1,2+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$. I find it straightforward to directly construct a domination of their counting processes. Just let them use the same underlying sample path for the Markov process, and couple the wait times until the first point, second point, etc. But I want to couple the point processes directly and get a domination, e.g. that wherever $N$ has a point, $N^*$ does as well. My best guess is to generate a Poisson number of points for each, coupled to get the domination, and then generate uniform locations for the points (coupled of course---except that $N^*$ might have a few additional points). This seems to work for this simple example, but what about more generally?

Question: for regular point processes $N,N^*$ with (random) conditional intensities $\lambda(t)\leq\lambda^*(t)$, what can I say about domination $N\prec N^*$ where they can be coupled so that $N^*$ has a point wherever $n$ does?

I do realize that I am being loose here, as I need a suitable filtration to make it more formal/rigorous.

Any thoughts or references is appreciated.

Comment: A poisson process with intensity f(x) can be constructed from one with intensity $\lambda > f$  by selecting any point that occurs in the constant intensity process with probability $\frac {f(x)} \lambda$. The same may work here.

Comment: @mike at first I was thinking that wouldn't work because my conditional intensities are random, but then it dawned on me that I just need to couple the intensities and view the point processes as thinnings of a Poisson point process on whatever space needed. Now simulating the random intensities could be difficult, but the theoretical question seems answered. Thanks for the hint!